# Почему следует инициализировать переменные при их объявлении?

Tags: c++

Почему следует инициализировать переменные при их объявлении?

Comment: Потому что потом этого сделать будет нельзя.

Comment: int a;
<...>
a = 5;

Comment: `a = 5;` не является инициализацией, это присваивание

Comment: в чем различия?

Comment: инициализация происходит однократно при вызове конструктора, а присваивание - когда угодно потом при вызове оператора =. Или никогда, если оператор не доступен `int const a; a = 5;`

Comment: ведь инициализация - это первоначальное присваивание значения, разница только в том, что инициализация выполняется один раз, а присваивание - сколько угодно раз.

Comment: @user7860670 так в чем различия то между int i=1 и int i;i=1 ?

Comment: @eri в первом случае инициализация, во втором присваивание. Присутствие `=` видимо вводит в заблуждение, выражение `int i=1;` не содержит присваивания, это синтаксис copy-initialization.

Comment: int i = 1; - это объявление и инициализация; int i; - это просто объявление; i = 1; - это уже инициализация. Если это не так, то я сильно запутался

Comment: @user7860670 мы понимаем что это называется по разному. в чем различия в работе этих вещей? или хотяб исключительный пример

Comment: я выше уже приводил пример `int const a; a = 5;`, собственно эффекты для примитивных типов будут одинаковые, а для пользовательских типов - очень по-разному

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как раз объявление не содержит инициализацию. Инициализация происходит при определении.

Имеет смысл инициализировать переменную, если она локальная нестатическая, потому что иначе там будет мусор и можно случайно к нему обратиться, вызвав неопределенное поведение. Да и после определения "инициализировать" переменную уже нельзя, можно только присвоить ей какое-то значение.

Answer (score 1):

Ну я не думаю, что прям обязательно ***следует*** их инициализировать при объявлении. Ну только в том случае, если у тебя *заранее есть значение* или значение переменной константное и стоит ее(переменную) проинициализировать.

Comment: А есть ли какие-то различия (может в выделении памяти или что-то вроде того), когда инициализируешь переменную, при её объявлении или после?

Comment: @Slad после ее инициализировать будет невозможно...

Comment: https://ravesli.com/urok-10-peremennye-initsializatsiya-i-prisvaivanie-v-s/#toc-3

Comment: Статья, в которой сказано, почему лучше проинициализировать переменную сразу

Answer (score 0):

Основная причина в том чтоб не забыть положить значение в эту переменную.
С переменными на стеке там оказажется значение с предыдущего вызова этой функции (например как в strtok). Со значениями на куче - нет гарантии что там будет в переменной.

Компилятор не выдаст предупреждения что переменная не инициализированна. При рефакторинге части кода могут быть переставленны местами и получим ошибку которую не поймает иде и компилятор.